# threading.BoundedSemaphore acquiring and releasing in sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, python-multithreading, semaphore

I have a list of Thread objects being passed a BoundedSemaphore. These threads are each started and joined on. As part of the run() process, each acquires a semaphore lock, runs its primary function (a call to an external, rate-limited API), and then releases the lock.

```
    class ThreadProvisioner

        def func_a(self):
            threads = []
            pool = threading.BoundedSemaphore(MAX_THREADS)
            for i in range(thread_count):
                x = ProcessAgents(pool=pool)
                threads.append(x)

            thread_output = []
            for thread in threads:
                thread.start()
                thread_output.append(thread.join())

            return thread_output

    class IndividualThread(threading.Thread):
        
         def __init__(self, pool):
             Thread.__init__(self)
             self.pool = pool
             self.output = {}

         def run(self):
             self.pool.acquire()
             self.func_b()
             self.pool.release()

         def join(self, *args):
             Thread.join(self, *args)
             return self.output

         def func_b(self):
             // do the thing
             self.output = output
```

On execution, it appears to execute entirely sequentially. Rather than allowing up to MAX_THREADS concurrently, only a single thread can be seen running next to MainThread. I've tried searching for similar issues and have seen none. Am I misinterpreting the documentation?